# Android Method TextUtils.regionMatches

Tags: android, charsequence, textutils

I has found this android method TextUtils.regionMatches

But for some reason, so it is not clear how this function works.

The function can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#regionMatches%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int%29

And the base code for this method here, 
http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java#220

Thanks for those who might shed some light on how the function is called.

Comment: Be wary, the TextUtils.regionMatches throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in some cases, which the Java version doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static boolean regionMatches (CharSequence one,
                   int toffset, CharSequence two, int ooffset, int len)
```

**Sample code:**

```
CharSequence one = "asdfQWERTYc1234";
CharSequence two = "ghjklzxcQWERTYg7890kl";
boolean match = TextUtils.regionMatches(one, 4, two, 8, 6);
```

match is true.

**Explanation:**

In charsequence one, start from `toffset` (4) and get a number of characters equal to `len` (6) => QWERTY

In charsequence two, start from `ooffset` (8) and get a number of characters equal to `len` (6) => QWERTY

Both charsequences match, so the method returns true.

Comment: Very Good, but also good to know, text if the string `one` is longer or equals with `toffert+len` and same for `two` else you will get a error.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this to check for "http" at the very first of a string and another example always helps visitors.

```
url = "url.without/protocol.info"; // will match
// url = "http://url.with/protocol.info"; // won't match

String match = "http";
if(!url.regionMatches(true, 0, match, 0, match.length())) {
    //do something
}
```